# Using service to share data between components

Tags: angular, service

I've been trying to share some data between two of my components. The components are both shown through the routerOutlet in my main component, which looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from './account.service';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
providers: [AccountService]
})
export class AppComponent  { 

constructor(public accountService:AccountService){

}

}
```

I have a login component where I'm trying to set a value in my service, like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from './account.service';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'login-component',
templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent  {


constructor(public accountService:AccountService){
}

setAccount(userName: string, password: string){
    this.accountService.setAccount(userName,password); 
} 

}
```

The setAccount method gets called from my template. Now, in another component, I'm trying to get the account from the service and display the username, which doesn't work. The other component looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from './account.service';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'home-component',
templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
})

export class HomeComponent  {  


constructor(public accountService:AccountService){
}
}
```

I'm displaying the username like this in the template:

```
{{accountService.getAccount().name}}
```

Finally, here's my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


export class Account{
name: string;
password: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AccountService  {  

private account = {name: "", password: ""};

getAccount(){

return this.account;
}

setAccount(username: string, password: string){
this.account.name = username;
this.account.password = password;
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It seems that the problem is that the page is reloaded when the second component gets displayed, which causes that service to restart? Here's the HTML of my login component, as I suspect the problem might be in here:

```
    <div class="topbar">
    <a title="Made for the University of Southern Denmark." href="login.html">
        <img src="img/sdulogo.png">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="logincontainer">
<img src="img/profilepic.png">
    <form action="/home">
        <div class="form-input">
            <input #username type="text" id="username" 
            placeholder="Enter Username" required>
        </div>

            <div class="form-input">
            <input #password type="password" id="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password" required>
        </div>
        <button (click)="setAccount(username.value, password.value)" type="submit" class="btn-login">LOGIN</button><br>
        <a href="http://www.google.dk">Create Account</a><br>
        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
        <p>{{accountService.getAccount().name}}</p>
    </form>


</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors messages in the console? If so, please add them to your question.

Comment: No error messages whatsoever.

Comment: What is the sequence of actions you're doing, as a user of your application, to go from the login page to the home page? My guess is that you reload the page.

Comment: @JBNizet That is exactly right, the page is actually reloading. I didn't think about that. How do I avoid it?

Comment: If you use router.navigate() to go to the home page after the login, that shouldn't happen. But you can't prevent a user from reloading a page, so you need to deal with this possibility anyway, for example by storing the ID/token of the user in local storage, and get back the user information from the server if it isn't available in memory. Storing the password, anywhere, is not a wise idea. Why do you need the password after login? Addendum: your form shouldn't have an `action` attribute. The authentication should be handled programmatically, from the login component.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't really need the password, I'm going to remove that. I'm not using router.navigate at the moment - I've updated my question with the HTML of my login component. I will try to look into how I can utilize the local storage.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md).

your service should look something like this:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class Account{
    name: string;
    password: string;
}

@Injectable()
    export class AccountService  {  

    private account: BehaviorSubject<Account>; 

   constructor() {
       this.account = <BehaviorSubject<Account>>new BehaviorSubject({});
   }
   getAccount(){
       return this.account.asObservable();
   }

   setAccount(username: string, password: string){
       this.account.next({name: username, password: password})
   }
}
```

then in your login.component.ts:

```
constructor(private accountService:AccountService){}

setAccount(userName: string, password: string){
    this.accountService.setAccount(userName,password); 
} 

ngOnInit(): void {
   // example of usage
    this.setAccount('admin', 'admin')
}
```

in your home.component.ts:

```
private account:Account;
constructor(private accountService:AccountService){}

getAccount() {
    this.accountService.getAccount().subscribe(account => this.account = account)
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // example of usage
    this.getAccount()
}
```

in your home template use it like this `{{account.name}}`

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding AccountService as the provider in app.component, can you try adding it as a provider in your NgModule ?

Comment: I've had it in my NgModule all along.

Comment: then please try removing it from the app component.

Comment: When a service is used as a provider in a specific component, a new instance of the service exists for that component itself. So in cases where we need services which share data across components, we must not specify them in providers of the components but in the NgModule only.